# How to optimize this code in python

Tags: python, dictionary, optimization, iterator, generator

I need to optimize this code, that basically checks if every character of string `s1` is contained in `s2`, taking in consideration doubles.

```
s1, s2 = list(s1), list(s2)
for s in s2:
    if s in s1:
        s1.remove(s)
    else:
        return False
return True
```

I did some research on `map`, iterators and generators, and I'm sure in one or more of these there is a solution, but right now I'm pretty confused and frustrated (I'm very new to python, just a couple weeks), so maybe you can help me understand what's the best strategy in this case. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the case. The `s1.remove(s)` is there only to avoid errors on duplicate chars. For example if `s1='aabcd'` and `s2='aaa'` will return `True` while it is false. How a list1 - list2 would help me? If I've got this wrong please explain me

Comment: It is not clear what exactly your expected output is. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Don't know the implementation of `in` in python, wouldn't this code lead to O(n^2) worst case?

nlogn solution would be to sort and check if they are equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution using [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) that will handle duplicated characters correctly:

```py
from collections import Counter
c1 = Counter(s1)
c2 = Counter(s2)
return all(c2[c]>=c1[c] for c in c1)
```

Comment: You don't want to use `>=`, you only want `==`. Other than that, good answer!

Comment: This is a good one, thanks! Is not `c2[c]>=c1[c]` but `c1[c]>=c2[c]` but yeah, great answer

Comment: @NoticeMeSenpai If s1 and s2 should contain exactly the same characters, then you're right, `==` should be used.

Otherwise, we may argue that it is not necessary to read s2 completely, and we could optimize further (especially if s2 is significantly longer than s1).

Comment: @AdrienMatissart what precisely happens if c2[c] doesn't exist? does it break and return False at that point or does it create c2[c] and set it to 0?

Comment: Counter values defaults to 0.
See the second block on https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: @AdrienMatissart heh, thanks I did not know that, should look over docs more closely :d

Answer (score 1):

You can count the number of occurrences of each character in both strings. You also don't need to make either string a list: strings are their own iterators.

First, create a `set` as sets have an average lookup of `O(1)`.
Then, iterate through the set and get the counts of each character. If any counts aren't equal, `return False`. It also scales much better as the size of the string grows, than your current solution:

```
s1 = 'Stack Overflow'
s2 = 'woltk fcrSeavO'

def equal_chars(s1, s2):
    chars = set(s2)
    for char in chars:
        if s1.count(char)!= s2.count(char):
            return False
    return True

print(equal_chars(s1, s2))
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight adjustment on Adrien's great answer which is (maybe?) more efficient:

```
from collections import Counter

s1 = "hello"
s2 = "helo"

def count_chars(s1,s2):
    c2 = Counter(s2)
    for k,v in Counter(s1).items():
        if c2[k] < v:
            return False
    return True

print (count_chars(s1,s2))
```

result:

```
False
```